# Currying Function with many parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, currying

I'm stuck on currying a function with many parameters. What I want to do is take the result of return function and pass it to the next functions.

What I want is similar to this

```
return this.function(
   this.function(
      this.function(this.data, this.filterCondition1),
      this.filterCondition2),
   this.filterCondition3
);
```

What it basically does is it takes some data, filters it by condition and then feeds it to the next filter that also takes in a second different condition

What I've tried is:

```
curryFunction(data, filter, filterFunction) =>{
   const filteredData = filterFunction(data)
   return helper( curryFilter, curryFunction) =>{
     return curryFunction(filteredData, curryFilter, curryFunction)
   }
}
```

However, this function returns a function at the end instead of a value. 
Basically, it's an infinite loop. How exactly would I go about solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying?rq=1, think again about it

Comment: you want to provide arguments infinitely ?

Comment: Thanks Moxxi, I was doing this function really late last night so I didn't read about the most important part about currying which is to reduce it down to one function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment of

> take the result of the previous function and pass it to the next, similar to add([1]).add(2).add(3), which will result in 6

I think it is might be better to implement via class function.

```js
class NumberResult {
  value = 0;
  
  constructor (value: number) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  function add(a: number) {
    this.value = this.value + a;
    return this;
  }
  
  function add(a: number[]) {
    // overload to handle array
  }
}

const result = new NumberResult(1);
result.add(1).add(2).add(3);
console.log(result.value);
```

Comment: The reason why i was using a curry is beause I wanted to do it in a functional way, without having to reassign var.

Comment: @AzureWorld don't really understand, can you provide a more concrete example of your use case?

Comment: What I want to do is basically chain a function: take the result of the previous function and pass it to the next, similar to add([1]).add(2).add(3), which will result in 6. I was able to come up with a solution while reading more about currying:   
`function curry(value, filter, func){ 
 let totalValue = func(value,filter);   
 return function helper(filter){   
  if(filter === undefined)  
  return totalValue;  
  else{ 
  totalValue += func(value, filter);  
 return helper;  
} .  
}`

Comment: Updated answer based on comment. The idea is returning the object for every function so next function can use it. But `rxjs` is moving from this semantics to the `.pipe(multiple functions)`, so this approach might have some limitations?